# How to compare two data sets and extract values

Tags: python

I require to compare and extract the values between two dataset:

Data set 1:

```
names=["station", "phase", "hour", "minute", "second"]
arr = pd.read_csv('arrival.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
station= arr[['st', 'phase']]
        ST    Phs
0      UCP    EP
1      CET    ES
2      AET    EP
3      YHL    ES
4      DHL    EP
5      UAG    ES
6      FAG    EP
7      PUR    ES
8      MUR    EP
9      RBB    ES
10     NBB    EP
```

Data set 02

```
names=["station", "long2", "lat2"]
st = pd.read_csv('station.txt',sep='\t',names=names)


     station     long2      lat2
0      CET  81.91500  56.82850
1      UCP  72.32200  37.16267
2      PUR  22.57900  93.61317
3      RUR  63.44883  77.83300
4      AET  11.52967  63.15267
5      PIL  73.25167  34.64967
6      NRB  13.27017  68.65167
7      WPR  83.14017  11.75200
8      TAL  72.46550  32.63183
```

WHAT REQUIRED: I need to compare each entry to the first column of dataset 1 with the first column of dataset 2. If it matches then we pick the corresponding values from the second column and then store as:

```
UCP    EP   72.32200  37.16267
CET    ES   81.91500  56.82850
```

Comment: Fill a `dict` keyed on the column in question from the first data set, and then iterate through the second dataset?

Comment: do you already try to use contat with join = "inner" ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#

Comment: `station.merge(st)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
st.merge(station, left_on='station', right_on='st', how='inner').drop(['st'],axis=1)
```

or

```
st.set_index('station').merge(station, left_index=True, right_on='st')
```